# Loop through an array with delay in Java

Tags: java, arrays, delay

This is my second post! Thanks again for the help on the previous thread.

Today I have a very stupid question that I couldnt find any great answer to on Stack or anywhere else. I'm sorry if this is a duplicated question.

I am looking for a way too loop trought an array, perform something and then wait a delay of 1 sec in Java.

Here is the array ;

```
String[] bros = {"LUMIDOS", "Papineau", "Tayeul"};
```

and here is where I want to perform an action for each members of that array.

```
        for(String s : bros){
            message = "/tell "+s.bros+" some random text here";
        }
```

Also I think that my iteration is wrong..

Comment: It needs to be noted that one should not normally "sleep" or otherwise delay in the main thread of a "GUI" application, since that will (in most environments) cause the application to freeze.  Of course it's perfectly fine to "sleep" in a command-line app.  Depending on the type of GUI support you use there may be other restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the current executing Thread to sleep for 1 sec after you perform the action. And, there was a small correction in accessing the element of the array.

```
for(String s : bros){
        message = "/tell " + s + " some random text here";
        Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Hello Kugathasan!

Thanks a lot for the answer! :)

But I tought that thread.sleep made the whole program freeze?

Is that true?

Comment: @Alde : If you have only one Thread and making it to sleep, will cause you whole program freeze.

Comment: Thanks! That's the exact answer I wanted! :)